# Deploy UWP to windows phone stopped working

Tags: windows-phone, uwp, windows-mobile

I'm building UWP application and deploy it to a lumia930 for testing.
I just click

> Store => Create app packages => No Windows Store => Auto increment
>   version and Create.

When finished the whole app packages is copied to the phone and I install the certificate and the program.
It used to work fine but suddenly the program didnt show up anymore in the apps list. The current version is 1.0.31.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried soft-resetting the device?

Comment: I did now but still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the phone devices, you need to manually install all the dependencies from the Dependencies/ARM folder of your app before installing the appxbundle. Failing to do so will result in a silent failure of the installation.

[image: File explorer on phone]

Another option is to turn on the device portal on the phone from settings > update & security > for developers.
One done, get the displayed url and open it from your computer web browser. Under the apps section, you will find the "install app" subsection which will properly deploy the application. you will have to manually declare the dependencies.

[image: turn on portal on phone]
[image: portal on desktop]

Comment: oh yes that was it. Thanks!